# Average value of $f(x)=\int_x^1\cos t^2\,dt$

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x)=\int_x^1\cos t^2\,dt$$

Question is to find it's average value over $[0,1]$.

please tell me how to start with the sum.

Comment: First start with the $TeX$.

Comment: is it $$\int_x^1\cos(t^2)dt$$

Comment: or you can start with $$\LaTeX$$

Comment: do you mean $\cos(t)^2=\cos(t)\cdot \cos(t)$ (easy to solve with $\cos(t)^2= 0.5+0.5\cos(2t)$) or $\cos(t^2)$ (not solvable but related to Fresnel intergral)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average value of $f$ over $[0, \: 1]$ is given by $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left(\int_x^1 \cos(t^2) \: dt\right) \: dx$. By Fubini's theorem, this equals $$\int\int_{0 \le x \le t \le 1} \cos(t^2) \: dx \: dt = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^t \cos(t^2) \: dx\right) \: dt = \\ = \int_0^1 t\cos(t^2) \: dt = \left[\frac{1}{2}\sin(t^2) + c\right]_0^1 = \boxed{\frac{\sin1}{2}}$$

Comment: `\iint` and `\iint\limits` might be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know those commands...

Answer (score 1):

*The sum*? Which sum? The average value of your function over $[0,1]$ is given by

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1}\cos(t^2)\,dt\,dx = \iint_{0\leq x\leq t\leq 1}\cos(t^2)\,dx\,dt \stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\cos(t^2)\,dx\,dt $$
i.e. by
$$ \int_{0}^{1} t\cos(t^2)\,dt = \left[\frac{1}{2}\sin(t^2)\right]_0^1 = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\sin 1.}$$